# Como criar uma div com height com uma valor prescrito que diminui ao redirecionar a tela

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, flexbox

Estou com dificuldade em criar uma div no qual a largura é de 580px com a media query em 767px, quando vou diminuindo a tela a div continua fixa no mesmo valor do height. Como eu faço para que a gif acompanhe junto quando se redirecionar a tela. Fiz uma gif de exemplo utilizando o site vice.com/pt_br

https://giphy.com/gifs/JT2H2houQNkjNOOWw6/html5[![
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body{
 background:#f2f0d5;
}

/*----- Div Mobile -----*/
@media (min-width:768px){
 .container{
  display:none;
 }
}

@media (max-width:767px){
 .container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 }

 .col-box-1{
  background:tomato;
  border-bottom:3px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height:590px;
 }

 .col-box-1 img{
  width:100%;
 }

 /*Podem ignorar essa parte*/
 .col-box-1 h3{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bolder;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#f2f0d5;
  font-size:2em;
  text-align:center;
 }
 /*Podem ignorar essa parte*/

 .col-box-2{
  border-bottom:3px solid black;
  padding:0 1em;
  font-family:arial;
 }

 .col-box-2 h1{
  padding-top:0.5em;
  font-size:1.6em;
 }

 .col-box-2 a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  cursor:pointer;
 }

 .col-box-2 p{
  padding-top:0.8em;
  padding-bottom:1em;
  font-size:0.8em;
 }
}
/*----- Div Mobile -----*/
```

```html
<!------ Div ------>
 <section class="container">
  <article class="col-box-1">
   <img src="">
   <h3>img</h3> <!--Podem ignorar essa parte-->
  </article>

  <article class="col-box-2"> 
   <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</a></h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in.</p>
  </article>
 </section>
 <!------ Div ------>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw3z3.gif)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw3z3.gif)

Comment: Você irá utilizar uma imagem dentro da div, isso? coloque width:100px e height:768px na div, e na img coloque width:100% height:100%; Outra alternatica é colocar a imagem como background da div e atribuir background-size:cover;

Answer (score 0):

Simples, na imagem coloque o css

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="IMG" style="width: 100%;max-width: 300px;">
```

no .col-box-1 adicione um text-center

```
.col-box-1{
 background:tomato;
 border-bottom:3px solid black;
 width:100%;
 height:590px; // EU REMOVERIA ISSO...!

 text-align: center; // ADICIONE iSSO!
}
```

width: 100% faz ela pegar todo espaço lateral, max-width fala o tamanho máximo que ela pode ficar, abaixo disso ela vai acompanhar o tamanho da div que ela esta, ou resolução da tela, ou seja responsiva.

ECEMPLO:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body{
  background:#f2f0d5;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
  .col-box-1{
    background:tomato;
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:590px;
  }

  .col-box-1 img{
    width:100%;
  }

  /*Podem ignorar essa parte*/
  .col-box-1 h3{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#f2f0d5;
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
  }
  /*Podem ignorar essa parte*/

  .col-box-2{
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    padding:0 1em;
    font-family:arial;
  }

  .col-box-2 h1{
    padding-top:0.5em;
    font-size:1.6em;
  }

  .col-box-2 a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .col-box-2 p{
    padding-top:0.8em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    font-size:0.8em;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <article class="col-box-1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uTc1gik.png">
  </article>

  <article class="col-box-2">
    <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</a></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que você precisar usar outra propriedade para medir a tela nesses casos é bastante utilizando o vh ou seja viewport height (altura da tela do dispositivo);

exemplo de como usar

```css
.header {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>.header</header>
<div>
```

**Referencias**

[W3C css units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)